# PHP GD Library cannot show picture

Tags: php, gd

I have problem with PHP's GD Library..I've made this script for showing some users stats, and it can't work.I don't know why but it just shows broken picture..How can i fix it ?

Thanks, sorry for bad english

```
                     header("Content-type: image/png");

        $image      = imagecreatetruecolor(320, 180);

            $online_ico = imagecreatefrompng("/files/online.png");


            $avatar = imagecreatefrompng("/files/default.png");


        $white  = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 240, 240);
        $green  = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 255, 0);
        $red    = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);
        $blue   = imagecolorallocate($image, 9, 105, 162);

        $user_id = "25";
        imagefill($image, 0, 0, $blue); 

        //labels
        imagestring($image, 5, 20, 20, "ID ", $white);
        imagestring($image, 5, 20, 40, "UN", $white);
        imagestring($image, 5, 20, 60, "stats", $white);
        imagestring($image, 5, 20, 80, "name", $white);
        //data
        imagestring($image, 5, 130, 20, $user_id, $white);
        imagestring($image, 5, 150, 40, $user_id, $white);
        imagestring($image, 5, 130, 60, $user_id, $white);
        imagestring($image, 5, 130, 80, $user_id, $white);

        imagecopy($image, $online_ico, 130, 41, 0, 0, 16, 16);
        imagecopy($image, $avatar, 280, 140, 0, 0, 35, 35);

        imagepng($image);
```

Comment: what's the exact error? which image is broken? are you sure it's not a 404 issue?

Comment: No it's not, it shows me this pic http://i.imgur.com/0Pdpp.png

Comment: Comment out the "header("Content-type: image/png");" line and see what PHP error/warning you get :)

Comment: @x3ro It shows me a lot of characters ... http://i.imgur.com/uyU6L.png

Comment: Does your script output *anything* else at all?  Do you have a closing PHP tag (`?>`) followed by a newline that is corrupting the output?

Comment: @user1245311 I just used your exact source and ran it on my local machine and it worked perfectly. As Brian said, you should remove the closing `?>` and make sure the opening `<?php` is on the first line, so that your image is not corruped. You also should call `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to identify any possible mistake you may have made elsewhere. If all that doesn't help, this could also be a problem with your PHP installation. There are probably some test-cases you can run to make sure your GDlib installation works as it should.